# CS error 1501 in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to turn on and off fires with the day night cycle i have setup in unity but I'm getting error CS1501 : No overload for method FireOn takes 0 arguments and can not figure out why i am getting this error. i have a class for the fire attached to the fire pit, the method I'm trying to call is

```
void FireOn (GameObject ParticleEmitter) {
    ParticleSystem particlesystem = (ParticleSystem)gameObject.GetComponent("ParticleSystem");
    particlesystem.enableEmission = true;
}
```

the day night cycle code I'm using to try and call the method is

```
    if (cur_time>22 || cur_time<9 && moon_alpha<1){
        moon_alpha+=Time.deltaTime*2f;
        NativeFireOnOff fire = new NativeFireOnOff();
        fire.FireOn();
    }
```

and help would be very much appreciated, thank you very much in advance

Comment: `void FireOn (GameObject ParticleEmitter)` - unless you also have `void FireOn ()` defined somewhere, I don't see why the error message is unclear.

Comment: iv tried passing GameObeject ParticleEmitter as a parameter but it gives me error cs1525 unexpected symbol ParticleEmitter

Comment: post the code where you've passed the game object as a parameter

Comment: if (cur_time>22 || cur_time<9 && moon_alpha<1){
   moon_alpha+=Time.deltaTime*2f;
   NativeFireOnOff fire = new NativeFireOnOff();
   fire.FireOn(GameObject ParticleEmitter);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of FireOn is declaring that the function takes an argument, of type GameObject, with name ParticleEmitter:

```
void FireOn (GameObject ParticleEmitter) {
```

You are calling the function with no arguments:

```
fire.FireOn();
```

So, you need to pass in a GameObject into your FireOn function. Wherever your particle emitter is, find that GameObject, and then pass it into FireOn:

```
fire.FireOn(<name of your particle system's GameObject>);
```

The error message is maybe a little misleading, but what it's really saying is that it tried to find a version of FireOn which takes no arguments, but it couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that it can't find a function `FireOn` with 0 parameter, because your function takes 1 parameter, `ParticleEmitter`. To fix it, you need to pass a GameObject when you call `FireOn` function.

The way you're passing the parameter is wrong:

```
fire.FireOn(GameObject ParticleEmitter);
```

Change it to:

```
fire.FireOn(ParticleEmitter);
```

By doing this you also need to declare a variable:

```
public GameObject ParticleEmitter;
```

Then assign it a game object from the inspector.